# Thrust inplace copy_if operation

Tags: c++, gpu, thrust

I wanted to know if you can use copy_if as an in-place operation?

i.e.

```cpp
void copy(thrust::device_vector<int> & input){
    auto end = thrust::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), thrust::placeholder.1_ < 10);
        input.erase(end, input.end());
}
```

is equivalent to:

```cpp
void copy(thrust::device_vector<int> & input){
        thrust::device_vector<FullOptixRayPayload> dest(input.size());
        auto destEnd = thrust::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), dest.begin(), thrust::placeholder.1_ < 10);
        dest.erase(destEnd, dest.end());
        input = dest;
}
```

(order does not matter to me. I just want to reduce the amount of device space allocation. The copy_if operation and data types are just placeholders)

Comment: Pretty sure that this isn't safe even though it doesn't seem to say so in the docs. The final operation in this algorithm is a scatter (after finding out the right output indices via a scan). Elements could be overwritten before being read by another thread.

Comment: That is what I assumed as well. Just wanted to make sure! The documentation is pretty bad and when it said it was a “stable” operation that confused me.

Comment: Not sure why I haven't seen it the first time, but it is actually documented in both the [old](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction_gafd4cd96b998ad2b3c336be1e24dc1f67.html) and [new](https://nvidia.github.io/thrust/api/groups/group__stream__compaction.html#function-copy-if) docs: "Precondition: The ranges `[first, last)` and `[result, result + (last - first))` shall not overlap.". They also both say "copy_if is stable, meaning that the relative order of elements that are copied is unchanged.", which is usually the meaning of "stable" in the Thrust context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nvidia.github.io/thrust/api/groups/group__stream__compaction.html#function-copy-if):

> Preconditions: The ranges [first, last) and [result, result + (last - first)) shall not overlap.

So no, one is not allowed to use `thrust::copy_f` in-place. The reason is probably that the algorithm would need to create an internal copy (especially costly due to the potential allocation) before scattering the data to the right positions safely.